# How can I count the lines of multiple csv that are in one folder?

Tags: r, csv, count, data.table

I have more than 500 ".csv" files in one folder. I wanted to count the total number of lines in each file because I want to confirm if the merge of all the files I did was correct.

I tried using length(count/fields) but I would like to create a loop to avoid doing it one by one. I am new to R so my programming skills are pretty basic. Is there a way I could use a code with files=dir("path")?

```r
length(count.fields(files, skip = 1))
```

Comment: are you on Mac/Linux? just use `wc -l /path/to/for/*` on the command line

Comment: You could also pass that from the R console with the `system` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pros of using `count.fields` is that it doesn't load the file into the memory. 
Thus, it should be faster than using `read.csv` or another function.

Get the list of files:

```
 files <- list.files(path, full.names=TRUE)
```

Get the number of rows in each file:

```
lapply(X = files, FUN = function(x) {
  length(count.fields(x, skip = 1))
 })
```

## Benchmark

```
library(rbenchmark)

benchmark("count.fields" = {
  lapply(X = files, FUN = function(x) {
    length(count.fields(x, skip = 1))
  })
},
"read.csv" = {
  lapply(X = files, FUN = function(x) {
    nrow(read.csv(x, skip = 1))
  })
},
"fread" = {
  lapply(X = files, FUN = function(x) {
    nrow(data.table::fread(x, skip = 1))
  })
},
replications = 1000,
columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed",
            "relative", "user.self", "sys.self"))


          test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
1 count.fields         1000    0.81    1.000      0.28     0.50
3        fread         1000    6.24    7.704      4.57     1.66
2     read.csv         1000    2.93    3.617      2.16     0.76
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R, the following should work (`fread` from FG7's reply is faster than `read.csv` for large files, but if a lot of cases `read.csv` will be fine):

```
files<-list.files(your.folder, full.names=TRUE)
file.lengths<-unlist(lapply(file, function(x) nrow(read.csv(files)))#number of rows per file
sum(file.lengths)#total number of rows in all files
```